# i have some problem with left join JPQL

Tags: java

there is something wrong with ths way i use left join,
and i dont understand what am i doing wrong.

can you see it?

```
select distinct r.globalRuleId,
       r.ruleId,                                                     
       sv.validFrom,
       pm.moduleId,
       nvl(min(rai.failedOnRegistration),0)

from TRules r,
     TSlaVersions sv, 
     TModuleFormulas mv, 
     TPendingModule pm,
     left join TRulesAdditionalInfo rai on r.ruleId = rai.ruleId

where r.slaVersionId = sv.slaVersionId
      and r.formulaId = mv.pk.formulaId
      and mv.pk.moduleId = pm.moduleId

group by r.globalRuleId,
         r.ruleId,                                                     
         sv.validFrom,
         pm.moduleId

order by pm.moduleId
```

Comment: Your code is formatted so badly that I can't even edit it in a proper way.

Comment: If you want answers here, I suggest you format your code properly.

Comment: How do you know there is something wrong? In which way does the actual result differ from the expected?

Answer (score 0):

After reformatting your source, I think it's easy to spot: There's a `,` before `left join`.

Proper formatting and indentation are really your best SQL friends. If you don't want to do this manually, I suggest using an SQL client like [SquirrelSQL](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/) :-)